# Accidentally deleted yum.repos.d/ directory in my Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03 machine

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, yum, amazon-ec2

By mistake i deleted yum.repos.d/ folder and all .repo files inside this folder using ***sudo rm -rf yum.repos.d/***

so now i am not able to install anything and also not able to update.

After deleted once again created same dir ***sudo mkdir yum.repos.d/*** but inside this .repo files are missing respect to my system

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Bellow listed my system details

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like the easiest thing to do could be to build another machine with the same OS and copy the files across.  Assuming you didn't add any custom repos.

Comment: Ok Thanks, but any alternative methods?

Comment: Fire up a new instance, copy the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Fire up a new instance, copy the directory.
- Alternatively download `distroname-repos.noarch.rpm` package and simply reinstall it. `sudo rpm --reinstall distroname-repos.noarch.rpm`.

To find out the package name, run this command:

```
rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Hopefully you'll then be able to google it.

Comment: Yes, with rpm i tried, but it's not working. If you don't mind can you suggest me or share me the proper links where I'll get .rpm file. Because the one i tried was not working. And it is asking for dnf dependency.

Comment: Since you RPM database is intact, run this command `rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d` - you'll get the package name.

Comment: Thanks, i found yum-3.4.3-150.73.amzn1.noarch and rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64 . downloaded second one and ran this command  sudo rpm --reinstall rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm . but not able to find first one ( yum-3.4.3-150.73.amzn1.noarch).

Comment: Please check if this file works for you: https://www16.zippyshare.com/v/xV3wRqAa/file.html I've managed to find *repo files but I'm not sure they are the ones you need.